# how to setup dns so that any domain will point to one ip

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind

I want to offer a service that allows people to use their own domain.
I want my dns server to return my server ip for any domain query so I don't have to setup every client's domain.
How can I achieve this? What should the client do and what my dns server configuration should be? lets say bind, but I will probably write something custom with evldns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for wildcard DNS records.

See this [question](https://serverfault.com/q/12124/6543) which is among these [results](https://serverfault.com/search?q=wildcard+dns). These will explain how to get names likes `x.foobar.com, y.foobar.com, *.foobar.com` to resolve to one IP address.

If instead you are looking for resolution of names like 
 `*.foo.com, *.bar.com, *.*.com`
 to the same address then you will have to setup each individually with your registrar *and then* on your nameserver as well.

I suppose you could cobble up an evldns server that answers every external query with the same A record. At the moment I can't think of a reason why your server should **not** do so, but there has to be one.

Comment: Is it enough to have the dns server just answer to A records with the same ip and clients setting up their domain to point to my dns server or I have to implement additional features for the dns server? I'm trying this right now and it dosen't seem to work and I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: It just took some time to propagate, it works! :)
I have set up an elvds that just answers A records with my server ip and it works

Comment: What happens when your internal DNS clients lookup an external address?

Comment: Fortunately my application will not need dns lookups, if it will in the future I will use ISP dns servers.